# How to trigger a CDAP pipeline using airflow operators?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-cloud-data-fusion, cdap

I have an onpremise CDAP data fusion instance with multiple namespaces. How to trigger the pipeline using airflow operators? I have tried exploring the airflow available operators and this page but not very helpful https://cloud.google.com/data-fusion/docs/reference/cdap-reference#start_a_batch_pipeline

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you already deployed the pipeline and you have the location, instance name and pipeline name of the pipeline you want to run. See [CloudDataFusionStartPipelineOperator()](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/_api/airflow/providers/google/cloud/operators/datafusion/index.html#airflow.providers.google.cloud.operators.datafusion.CloudDataFusionStartPipelineOperator) for the parameters that it accepts.

Using the [quickstart pipeline](https://cloud.google.com/data-fusion/docs/quickstart), I triggered the pipeline using `CloudDataFusionStartPipelineOperator()`. See operator usage below:

```
import airflow
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.operators.datafusion import CloudDataFusionStartPipelineOperator

YESTERDAY = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)

default_args = {
    'owner': 'Composer Example',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'email': [''],
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': datetime.timedelta(minutes=5),
    'start_date': YESTERDAY,
}

with airflow.DAG(
        'trigger_df',
        'catchup=False',
        default_args=default_args,
        schedule_interval=datetime.timedelta(days=1)) as dag:

    start_pipeline = CloudDataFusionStartPipelineOperator(
        location='us-central1',
        pipeline_name='DataFusionQuickstart',
        instance_name='test',
        task_id="start_pipeline",
    )

    start_pipeline
```

Success "Graph View":

[image]

Logs:

[image]

Comment: Wonderful example for cloud data fusion. Thanks. But I am looking for CDAP the on premise instance of data fusion. A similar example will be very helpful. When I say on premise there will be a host, port and user authentication required to connect